# Why can lambdas convert function calls into Actions?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

In this code fragment:

```
List<String> names = new List<String>();
names.Add("Bruce");
names.Add("Tom");
names.Add("Tim");
names.Add("Richard");

names.ForEach(x => Print(x));

private static string Print(string s)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
    return s;
}
```

`Print` is not an `Action` for sure since it is returning `string`; however `x=> Print(x)` is, why?

Comment: Please improve the title of this question.  Google uses it to title its search results, and your title is not Googlable at all.

Answer (score 16):

The type of the lambda expression `x => Print(x)` is determined based on its context. Since the compiler knows that the lambda is assigned to `Action<string>`, the compiler disregards the return type of the `Print(s)` method as if it were a *statement expression*.

This is a valid conversion:

```
Action<string> myAction = y => Print(y);
```

In other words, both

```
Print("something");
```

and

```
int x = Print("something");
```

are correct usages of the `Print` method; they can be used in lambdas in the same way.

Comment: Since Print returns string, why compiler can take the return type as void and match Action?

Comment: Because a legal thing to do with the string is throw it away. You don't need to specifically state that you are throwing away a return value -- not using it is sufficient.

Comment: In fact, almost every time you are assigning a variable, you are doing the same thing, since assignment expressions return the assigned value!  So an action that assigns a raible is doing the same thing.

Answer (score 10):

`x => Print(x)` is a lambda that is turned into a method here equivalent to:

```
void MyPrintLambda(string x) { Print(x); }
```

If the context had called for, say, a `Func<string, string>`, it would have been this:

```
string MyPrintLambda(string x) { return Print(x); }
```

Or if it was a `Func<string, object>`, it would have been this:

```
object MyPrintLambda(string x) { return Print(x); }
```

Because the compiler can turn `x => Print(x)` into an `Action<string>` by simply ignoring the return type (i.e. the first example), it can compile.

Comment: The last bit isn't quite correct, `names.ForEach(Print)` won't compile, as `Print` is NOT convertible to an `Action<string>`, `x => Print(x)` is, however, since expressions' types are defined based on usage

Answer (score 4):

For the same reason that this would be valid:

```
foreach (string name in names)
{
    Print(name);
}
```

The Print() method returns a value in that code as well, but no one would expect this to be an error. It's allowed to just throw away the return value.