# Why does assigning an async await event handler not cause any problems?

Tags: c#, .net

Given the following code:

```
delegate void TestEventHandler();

event TestEventHandler TestEvent;

void Main()
{
    TestEvent += () => Console.WriteLine("Sync");
    
    TestEvent += async () => await AsyncHandler();
    
    TestEvent();
}

private async Task<int> AsyncHandler()
{
    await Task.Delay(200);
    Console.WriteLine("Async");
    
    return 5;
}
```

I'd like to know why this does not cause any problems. Doesn't `async () => await AsyncHandler()` return a Task? In this example it is assignable to a delegate returning void?

Also, does this cause any problems? Is making an even handler async... that easy? I'm wondering where a potential exception might be caught in this case.

For comparison, the following code in the above sample:

```
var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 5).Select(async _ => await AsyncHandler());

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

This produces, as expected, a collection of `Task`. So why is it a Task now, but above it counts as void?

Comment: only one ... if your throw something from AsyncHadler you could not catch it with `try { TestEvent(); } catch (Exception ex) { ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code:

```
TestEvent += async () => await AsyncHandler();
```

...the compiler is inferring the type of the lambda expression. It infers a type that matches the delegate. It is more or less the same as doing this:

```
var action = new Action(async () => await AsyncHandler());  //<-- not a Func<Task>!
TestEvent += action;
```

You'll notice that you are not assigning a function to the event but an action.

If you're wondering how an action can be inferred from a function, see [Why can lambdas convert function calls into actions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12869426/why-can-lambdas-convert-function-calls-into-actions).